Custom extractable_from concept for operator>> and streams
I have a function template that has two parameters. I need to ensure that the type template argument passed to it is extractable using operator>>( std::istringstream& iss, T& value ).
A minimal example:
template <class T>
std::istringstream&
extract_field_from_line( std::istringstream& iss, T& value )
{
// ...
    iss >> value;
    return iss;
}

I came up with the following concept:
template <class T, class S>
concept extractable_from = requires ( S& stream, T& value )
                           {
                            { stream >> value } -> std::same_as<S&>;
                           };

So something like this would be possible:
template <class T>
requires( extractable_from<T, std::istringstream> )
std::istringstream&
extract_field_from_line( std::istringstream& iss, T& value )
{
// ...
    iss >> value;
    return iss;
}

Is this concept sufficient and sane? Could anything be improved here?

It looks ok to me, but why do you want SFINAE in this situation? Will there be extract_field_from_line versions where T can't be extracted from the stream? The name is a bit odd too. stream instead of line would be better i.m.o.

@TedLyngmo This is to simplify debugging. Some of the types in the future might not have an overloaded extraction operator. This concept helps in diagnosing the problem. I currently don't see another benefit.

Ok, but wouldn't a static_assert be even clearer in those cases?

@TedLyngmo You mean I should use the concept in the condition of a static_assert with a message?

Yes, that would be my suggestion, unless you actually need SFINAE.

@JeJo What idea? Preventing the mentioned bug?

Your concept looks fine, there is already a similar exposition-only concept in the standard, stream-extractable.

@康桓瑋 Nice. So I guess mine will serve my needs.

I think it's not unusual for the return type to be different from the input type given it's a polymorphic hierarchy, e.g. something like std::ostream&, so I would personally change the same_as to a formulation of derived_from
